# White image when resizing Tbitmap

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, tbitmap

This code is supposed to resize a `TBitmap`, but the resulting bitmap is just a white image (with the final size). I'm using it to resize to a lower size.

```
function ResizeBitmap(B: TBitmap; Width, Height: Integer): TBitmap;
var
  finalbitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  finalbitmap := TBitmap.Create(Width, Height);
  finalbitmap.Clear(0);
  if finalbitmap.Canvas.BeginScene then
  try 
    finalbitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(B, RectF(0,0,B.Width,B.Height), RectF(0,0,Width,Height), 1);
  finally
    finalbitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
  Result := finalbitmap;
end;
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: `Clear()` is still a drawing operating, and as such it should be called between `(Begin|End)Scene()`. Though, it shouldn't really matter since `DrawBitmap()` will just draw over everything `Clear()` would have drawn, so there is really no need to call `Clear()` at all, unless `B` has transparency to it and you want `finalbitmap` to also have transparency. But, did you verify that `BeginScene()` is not returning False in your situation?

Comment: Yes, I verified it. The process goes into the if so BeginScene is returning True.

Comment: In a simple test I did, I could not reproduce the problem. Please also show the code that calls `ResizeBitmap()`

Comment: I saw the code you added earlier, and I copied it for myself to test it later. Now I see that you have deleted the comment with the code. Does that mean that you found a solution yourself? If so, the proper thing to do **if the q/a could be beneficial for other readers, is to answer your own question**. If, on the other hand, the problem was a silly error or mistake, then the proper thing to do is to delete the question also. If you can't delete (because of insufficient reputation) let us know and somebody here can close it. (BTW, was the reason incompatible image types, png v. bmp?)

Comment: No, but I had another problem and I thought it was related... so I wanted to try before I waste your time... but not solved...

Comment: `code function u(im:TBitmap):string;
var
....
begin
  try
    thumbnailtoload:=TBitmap.Create;
    thumbnailtoload:=ResizeBitmap(imagetoload,200,120);
    tpath:=system.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(system.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'hola.jpg');
    thumbnailtoload.SaveToFile(tpath);
    PostData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    IdHTTP1:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    PostData.AddFile('file', tpath,'image/*');
    idhttp1.Post(SERV+'up.php?dir=pic/', PostData);
  finally
    PostData.Free;
    idhttp1.Free;
  end;
  result:=filename;
end; `

Comment: If I upload the image witouth the resize, it is ok.

Comment: Maybe this could help... If the extension of the image is .jpg the result is a black image. If it's .png the result is a white one...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've modified the php to resize the uploaded image. I'm not able to know what is wrong with my delphi code.

```
<?php 
$uploaddir = strval($_GET['dir']); 
$newwidth = strval($_GET['newwidth']); 
$newheight = strval($_GET['newheight']); 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
$sourceProperties = getimagesize($uploadfile);
$fileNewName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$imageType = $sourceProperties[2];
$imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($uploadfile); 
$targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1],$newwidth,$newheight);
imagepng($targetLayer,$uploaddir. "thumb". $fileNewName);
move_uploaded_file($uploadfile, $uploaddir. $fileNewName. ".". "png");

function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height,$twidth,$theigth) {
    $targetWidth =$twidth;
    $targetHeight =$theigth;
    $targetLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($twidth,$theigth);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$twidth,$theigth, $width,$height);
    return $targetLayer;
}
?>
```